# What's the best way to enter a contract start/end date in an Opportunity?

Tags: opportunity, date

I want to keep track of how long each opportunity is for, a 3 or 6 or 12 month contract for example, and report off this info. Should I just add a start/end date or is there a better way to enter this info?

Comment: Are you creating a new Contract object off of the opportunity once it is won?  If so what is the process for that?  Manual, Trigger, etc.

Comment: Yes once it's won. Manually.

Comment: So is this contract length field you want to have on the opportunity simply to alert the user creating the contract the length it needs to be?  Or does it have other significance?

Comment: Mostly to report off of (# of requests by time period) also so if we say a contract is $1,000 and most are $500 we know that this might be because the time periods differ (12 vs 6 month contracts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Case 1:**

If Opportunities have fixed set of contract period, then create picklist "3 months", "6 months", "12 months" etc.

Also this created picklist can be a dependent picklist and could be available only when Parent picklist is set to some value (say "Closed Won").

**Case 2:**

If Opportunities can have variable months or years, then create "Start Date" and "End Date". Create an another formula field which calculates the difference between End Date and Start Date in months and name it as "Contract Period".

Now, "Contract Period" field can be used in reports as per your requirement.